# Gestión de archivos Laravel en hosting compartido

Tags: laravel, archivo, hosting

porfas me pueden ayudar, resulta que tengo un proyecto laravel en un hosting compartido

> /proyecto                => en la raíz tengo los archivos base del proyecto laravel
>
> /public_html/proyecto  => en la public tengo Los archivos del public del proyecto laravel

El problema se me presenta al intentar mostrar imágenes que subo en el storage/app/public.
Estoy guardando en la base de datos estos 2 campos

```
name : nombreimagen.jpg
path : public/cedulas/8wd7O3WmV6VixzmQbOsBkSjapG7zQD9WM6IFnhFn.jpeg
```

y estoy intentando mostrar la imagen de la siguiente forma

```
<img  src="{{ asset('/public/cedulas/8wd7O3WmV6VixzmQbOsBkSjapG7zQD9WM6IFnhFn.jpeg')}}">
```

Y no logro visualizar la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#configuration) de Laravel (5.8):

> ... To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic
>   link from public/storage to storage/app/public. This convention will
>   keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be
>   easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment
>   systems like Envoyer...

Es decir, para poder acceder desde la web a tus archivos del `storage` se crea un enlace *simbólico* (symbolic link) con el comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Una vez hecho esto podrías acceder a tus archivos de la siguiente forma:

```
<img  src="{{ asset('storage/cedulas/8wd7O3WmV6VixzmQbOsBkSjapG7zQD9WM6IFnhFn.jpeg') }}">
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, realice la prueba de lo que me comentaste pero no me muestra la imagen, la imagen esta guardada efectivamente en el servidor pero la url que se genera no la muestra.

Comment: He editado la respuesta: Tienes que poner `storage/cedulas/...` en vez de `public/cedulas/...`

Comment: Efectivamente funciona correcto lo que me comentas compañero, agregue un enlace simbólico en la carpeta public_html/miproyecto

Comment: No entendí como hacerlo con laravel, asi que genere un archivo .php y lo ejecute dentro de la carpeta public_html dejo el código, así que lo dejo aquí en caso de que alguien lo necesite en un futuro

Comment: <?php symlink('/home/hosting/miproyecto/storage/app/public', '/home/public_html/miproyecto/storage');

Answer (score 0):

despues de varias hora analizando encontre la solucion, si estas en un hosting compartido y tienes varios sitios la solucion es muy facil solo debes configurar el cpanel entras a dominios y configuras el directorio raiz a la carpeta storage/app ejemplo dominio.com.co/storage/app y listo

por si editaron provider
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider; si colocaron codigo deben dejarlo como estaba vacio

en el archivo index de la carpeta public

require **DIR**.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';